# how to make nested bitbucket API http request in ngrx effects

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

BitBucket API 1.0 returns tags with no timestamp. Example response:

```
{
  "size": 2,
  "limit": 2,
  "isLastPage": false,
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "refs/tags/tag1",
      "displayId": "tag1",
      "type": "TAG",
      "latestCommit": "ff7be6fad2e660e8139f410d2585f6b2c9867a61",
      "latestChangeset": "ff7be6fad2e660e8139f410d2585f6b2c9867a61",
      "hash": "f13db8e5c0b75b57b48777299d820525ad8127b9"
    },
    {
      "id": "refs/tags/tag2",
      "displayId": "tag2",
      "type": "TAG",
      "latestCommit": "4f5878c9554444755dbf6699eac33ff8752add5f",
      "latestChangeset": "4f5878c9554444755dbf6699eac33ff8752add5f",
      "hash": "23274bd5c9b87614f14a2245d5e70812c83104b7"
    }
  ]
}
```

Therefore I am trying to request the latestCommit to get it's data. The response retrieves the committerTimestamp which I want to add to the tag object.

The ngrx effect and a following function are written as follows:

```
@Effect()
  loadTags: Observable<LoadTagsRes> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BitbucketActionTypes.LOAD_TAGS_REQ),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.http.get('https://bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/projects/repos/project/tags?limit=2', httpOptions).pipe(
        map((response: any) => response.values.map(tag => (
            {
              ...tag,
              timeStamp: this.getTagTimestamp(tag.latestCommit)
            }
          ))
        ),
        map((response: any) => new LoadTagsRes({tags: response}))
      )
    }),
  );

  getTagTimestamp(tag) {
    return this.http.get<any>(`https://bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/projects/repos/project/commits/${tag}`, httpOptions).pipe(
      switchMap(res => {
        return res;
      })
    );
  }
```

the new timeStamp property in the array of objects displays the following in redux devtools:
[image]

Would like to get the correct response for the inner http request.

Answer (score 0):

The function should trigger the secondary request and fetch the timestamp but it isn't being triggered yet. You need to use `switchMap` (or any other RxJS higher order mapping operator) to trigger it. And seeing that you have multiple requests, you could use RxJS `forkJoin` function to trigger them in parallel.

Try the following

```js
@Effect()
loadTags: Observable<LoadTagsRes>= this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(BitbucketActionTypes.LOAD_TAGS_REQ),
  switchMap(() => {
    return this.http.get('https://bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/projects/repos/project/tags?limit=2', httpOptions).pipe(
      switchMap((response: any) => {
        forkJoin(response.values.map(tag =>
          this.getTagTimestamp(tag.latestCommit).pipe(
            map(timeStamp => ({...tag, timeStamp: timeStamp}))
          )
        ))
      }),
      map((response: any) => new LoadTagsRes({
        tags: response
      }))
    )
  }),
);
```

Comment: getting the following error:  error TS2345: Argument of type '(response: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.

tried switchMap((response: any): any to avoid the error but the app state is not updated

Comment: It seems you're attempting to assign variables of wrong type of each other. Please check the return types and the assignments.

Answer (score 0):

```
  loadTags: Observable<LoadTagsRes> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(BitbucketActionTypes.LOAD_TAGS_REQ),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.http.get('https://bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/projects/repos/project/tags?limit=2', httpOptions).pipe(
        mergeMap((response: any) => response.values.map(tag => {
        // array of observables
          const tag$=this.getTagTimestamp(tag.latestCommit);

        // use forkJoin to return single observable that returns array of results
         return forkJoin(tag$)
        })
        ),
        map((response: any) => new LoadTagsRes({tags: response}))
      )
    }),
  );

  getTagTimestamp(tag) {
    return this.http.get<any>(`https://bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/projects/projects/repos/project/commits/${tag}`, httpOptions).pipe(
      switchMap(res => {
        return res;
      })
    );
```

Comment: it returns the following array to the state:
[{_isScalar: false}, {_isScalar: false}]